# Prove that the sum of the cubes of n real numbers is zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Today I came across this problem.

> The sum of n real numbers is zero and the sum of their pairwise products is also zero. Prove that the sum of the cubes of the numbers is zero.

I tried to solve it in the following way
$$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n = 0$$
Squaring both sides
$$a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2+2(0)=0$$
$$a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2=0$$
However I am unable to move further and get any close to $a_1^3+a_2^3+\ldots+a_n^3=0$. Any help would be appreciated. Also this is a part of an exercise on the topic "No Square is Negative".

Comment: As you mentioned , squares are always nonnegative. Hence , a sum of squares can only be $0$ , if all squares are $0$. So, we get $a_i=0$ for all $i$

Comment: Indeed, so this answered your question: [How Can I prove that $x_1^2+x_2^2+......+x_n^2>0$ by matematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068117/how-can-i-prove-that-x-12x-22-x-n20-by-matematical-induction)

Comment: @Henry I used the property that square of the sum of n numbers is equal to the sum of squares of those n numbers and twice their pairwise products to prove the sum of squares = 0.

Comment: @Henry Nobody meant that pairwise products means squares.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for showing me the obvious conclusion which I had missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $a_k\in \mathbb{R}$ $a_k^2 \geq 0$ holds.
Hence $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 =0$ implies $a_k=0$ for every $k=1,...,n$. And of course $a_k^3=0^3=0$ follows aswell.